# Input redirection into Java - Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I tried every online solution and i still get the same result..i'm trying to get my code to run on a file "distinct.txt" and here is my attempt to run it.

[image: here is my try]

i tried different paths and all give same result.

here is my code

```
package pset2.sol;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdIn;
public class Permutation {
public static void main(String[] args){
    RandomizedQueue<String> rq = new RandomizedQueue<>();
    while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
        String item = StdIn.readString();
        rq.enqueue(item);
    }
    int k = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){
        System.out.println(rq.dequeue());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Add code as text. not as image

Comment: You have to compile the java file first, And you have to run it from the folder that contains pet2 folder

Comment: @Jens i'm not adding the pic for the code i'm adding it to show what i wrote in the terminal but here is my code anyway http://pastebin.com/QznjZ44d.. can u tell me how to compile it first ? and i'm already running it through the folder which contains pset2 which is "production"..i'm beginner so i might miss understand some stuff

Comment: to campile code you have to use `javac`

Comment: it gives me this error 
javac: file not found: Permutation.java

Comment: Do you see an out folder above the src folder?

Comment: yeah i fixed that error when i changed directory to src/pset2/sol..
but when it compiles it gives me 
error: cannot find symbol
 RandomizedQueue<String> rq = new RandomizedQueue<>();
this error deosn't appear when i run it through the green button. "RandomizedQueue" is class in the same directory..any idea whats wrong?

Comment: As far as I can tel from the directory, all your files have a green 'play' logo. This means that all of them have a main method. You should only have have 1 main method and instantiate the objects there. Also since this is a code question now, can you also put your code up as well? Thanks

Comment: i added the code and commented the main methods in other files so only Permutation have main method..still same error but i don't know why i can run it normally from the green play button?

Comment: Okay could you show me the RandomizedQueue class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134799/discussion-between-ishnark-and-ahmad-fahmy).

Answer (score 27):

My guess is that your source-folder is not set correctly.

Try File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> (tab) Sources -> Mark as: Sources.

That fixed the problem for me after importing an Eclipse Project.

Answer (score 18):

You have to make sure that the "Project compiler output" value is set, in `Project Structure > Project`, and that the module's Compiler output points to a valid path:

[image]
[image]

Comment: It seems that the path must be a fully qualified path, not relative.

Comment: It's strange, but it really helped me to resolve my issue

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should always use the green button from IntellIJ. You can set the Edit Configurations to give the path to the file. I don't know about reading in the file from stdin through there, though.

---

Your problem is not IntelliJ, though, it's the CMD.

First, make sure you are in the right folder.

Run `cd /path/to/compiled_files` to see that you are at the parent of the `pset` folder.

```
pset
   /sol2
      Permutation.class
```

Then, you'll likely need a classpath to have the other classes within the `pset.sol2` package to be resolved.

```
java -cp . pset.sol2.Permutation
```

More details: [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Answer (score 1):

In intellij, choose Run. | Edit Configurations from the main menu.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

A bit late to the party here, but I found that my Main file (in the source file), was missing the ".java" extension, even though the file looked fine in the intelliJ project explorer.

However on close inspection, I noticed that the file type in /out/ was not a class file (i.e. did not have the blue circle with a "C" in).

I think this could be because I created the "main" file in my source folder, before I marked that folder as source in the project settings, and the file type created was undefined somehow...

To fix, I renamed the Main file to Main.java (in finder), and rebuilt the project from the build menu.