# Spring Boot Program cannot find main class but worked with spring-boot:run

Tags: spring-boot

I searched the same problem, but the answers did not resolve my problem.
I developed the spring boot application with `IntelliJ IDEA`, here is my MainClass:

```
package me.yummykang.configserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.EnableConfigServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And my pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>me.yummykang</groupId>
    <artifactId>config-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>config-server</name>
    <description>config server</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>me.yummykang</groupId>
        <artifactId>eagle-eye</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

The project is a multiple modules maven project, another sub module can run using IDEA's DEBUG button, but this sub module can not run with IDEA's DEBUG button and cause `***ERROR:Could not find or load main class Could not find or load main class me.yummykang.configserver.ConfigServerApplication***`

But I could run it using the spring boot plugin execute the **run** command and other command like **start** would did not work as well. And after shuting down the application that started with `**run** command,` the IDEA's DEBUG button worked because of the target that was compiled by `**run**` command.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027117/input-redirection-into-java-could-not-find-or-load-main-class

Comment: I searched that but did not help.

Comment: Having similar issue. The offender is this library: spring-cloud-config-server. If you remove it everything becomes normal. Haven't figured out the fix yet...

Answer (score 0):

- Please configure/update appropriate JRE into Build path and compiler
  in the IDE.
- Run javac and java in command, check if both are same
  Java versions.
- Update Java version in pom.xml.

---

```
<properties>        
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version></spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```